# Do I need to install Tomcat? I have installed JBoss for load balancing with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss, load-balancing, mod-jk

I'm trying to working on load balancing, so is there a need to install Tomcat as well? Or is JBoss enough with Apache and mod_jk module.

And how can I test load balancing, if it it working or not? Can we have a simple way to test by looking at logs or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

[Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is bundled with [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss), so there is no need to install it separately. Apache and mod_jk should be enough to load balance JBoss instances.

You can easily confirm that load balancing is working by looking at the JBoss access log files.

Comment: I think you meant Jboss is bundled with Tomcat not the other way round :)

Comment: tomcat is a web/servlet container ; jboss is a j2ee application server. tomcat is bundled with jboss and not the other way around !